# Applying pandas qcut bins to new data

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pandas qcut to split some data into 20 bins as part of data prep for training of a binary classification model like so:

```
data['VAR_BIN'] = pd.qcut(cc_data[var], 20, labels=False)
```

My question is, how can I apply the same binning logic derived from the qcut statement above to a new set of data, say for model validation purposes. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can do it by passing `retbins=True`.

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
prng = np.random.RandomState(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(prng.randn(100, 2), columns = ["A", "B"])
```

`pd.qcut(df["A"], 20, retbins=True, labels=False)` returns a tuple whose second element is the bins. So you can do:

```
ser, bins = pd.qcut(df["A"], 20, retbins=True, labels=False)
```

`ser` is the categorical series and `bins` are the break points. Now you can pass bins to `pd.cut` to apply the same grouping to the other column:

```
pd.cut(df["B"], bins=bins, labels=False, include_lowest=True)
Out[38]: 
0     13
1     19
2      3
3      9
4     13
5     17
...
```

Comment: Great answer. Hopefully this helps someone as dunderheaded as me: *it is ```qcut``` (with a "q") as the first step and ```cut``` (without a "q") in the second step* :)

Comment: By using this logic, I am getting Na values in my validation set. Is there some way to solve it?

Comment: @Karen I posted a solution to this problem (a few years too late).

Answer (score 2):

User @Karen said:

> By using this logic, I am getting Na values in my validation set. Is there some way to solve it?

If this is happening to you, it most likely means that the validation set has values below (or above) the smallest (or greatest) value from the training data. Therefore, some values will fall out of range and will therefore not be assigned a bin.

You can solve this problem by extending the range of the training data:

```py
# Make smallest value arbitrarily smaller
train.loc[train['value'].eq(train['value'].min()), 'value'] = train['value'].min() - 100
# Make greatest value arbitrarily greater
train.loc[train['value'].eq(train['value'].max()), 'value'] = train['value'].max() + 100
# Make bins from training data
s, b = pd.qcut(train['value'], 20, retbins=True)
# Cut validation data
test['bin'] = pd.cut(test['value'], b)
```

Comment: Hey, is there a way to get this saved from my pickled model file and use it another file where i will be loading the same model ??

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. You mean you want to extend the ranges from your pickled model?

Why not write a little pipeline in the script that loads the pickled model instead?